# How to check if user is in high contrast mode via JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, css, high-contrast

When pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> Windows switches into high contrast mode - is there any chance to detect that on a web page (using JavaScript or CSS)?

Is there any chance to detect that in the `HTTP-Request` (a.k.a the server-side e.g. via PHP or Ruby)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this article about using CSS sprites in high contrast](http://hardlikesoftware.com/weblog/2009/11/04/css-sprites-vs-high-contrast-mode/), in high contrast mode on Windows, background images should be set to "none" and it also changes the background color. This should override any CSS stylesheet. So you can perform some javascript to detect it after initial rendering. Check his [demo page](http://hardlikesoftware.com/projects/HCMtest.html) (the "FYI [Not] in high contrast mode" text).

I have Mac (FYI switch using `Cmd + Alt + Ctrl + 8`) and his technique doesn't work for me, but he says it works on Windows.

If it works, you can either use some JavaScript to simply change your CSS or set a (session) cookie and reload the page to pass it to the server and perform server-side actions.

Comment: This response doesn't answer the question, which was: how can a developer determine whether or not a user is in high-contrast mode?  This response (and the accompanying link) provides suggestions on what to do *after* determining the user is in high-contrast mode.

Comment: No, the _reasoning_ is sound: HCM overrides colors and background images, and this should be able to be detected with JavaScript. In the currently current Chrome 118, the demo does not work, but this is (at least partially) because it relies on JQuery, but that fails to load due to an HTTP/HTTPS mismatch.

Answer (score 4):

The following works for me on Win8 with (the desktop-)IE:

```
<style type="text/css">
// ...
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
   /* any rules may come here, for example: */
   .leftMenu a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }
}
// ...
</style>
```

I think it must work with Windows Store Apps as well.
This is not a complete solution, but maybe useful a bit.

MSDN doc: [@media](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh997007.aspx),
[-ms-high-contrast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465764.aspx).
The [High-contrast mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh848048%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) description is also worth mentioning.

Comment: Thanks you so much for pointing me in right direction. Another advantage of using @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active) style is that you can set the background-image attribute once again to override the high contrast image settings.

Comment: This only works in Internet Explorer, not in Firefox. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=425598

Answer (score 2):

Use [@media (prefers-contrast: more)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/prefers-contrast):

```css
.contrast {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  outline: 2px dashed black;
}

@media (prefers-contrast: more) {
  .contrast {
    outline: 2px solid black;
  }
}
```

It's [supported in all major evergreen browsers](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_at-rules_media_prefers-contrast).

Warning: `-ms-high-contrast` only works in Microsoft browsers.

Answer (score 1):

If you are implementing high contrast in your web application then use following code block for detecting black-on-white and white-on-black contrast selection. This will work fine in IE.

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: black-on-white) {
 /*
 Put your styling code.............
  */
  }

@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: white-on-black) {
 /*
Put your styling code.............
*/
  }